# How to add own language model to java program using sphinx 4

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, sphinx4

I've successfully created the language model and other files using sphinxbase, sphinxtrain etc. I've now following list of files

```
an4.dic
an4.lm
an4.lm.bin
feat.params
mdef
means
mixture_wights
noisedict
transition_matrices
variances
```

Now i ve to create a java application that can use those models but i couldn't find any tutorial for that can any one help to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list contains acoustic model files, language model and dictionary. These are used for different purposes in different components of CMU Sphinx.

The simplest thing to do would be to get an existing example from Sphinx4 web page and replace the existing files with yours.